# GoogleMaps is taking too long to load after the page is loaded

Tags: html, css, maps

I have included a custom loader in a page which also includes GoogleMaps. After the page is loaded the map takes too long to load.

Comment: You question don't have much information.. please add more details..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the latest GoogleMaps Api version.

Also, you could display a [Static Image of the map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/?csw=1) while the map loads for better UX.

Anyway, it would be easier to help you if you provided some code, because at this point, we're not even sure that the map itself is causing the problem.